# Read the graphic at another value

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

So I got this code and I'm new at coding, what I want to do is just read the graphic at a value of the Y axis and get the value of the X axis

```
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == (0.16 - 0.0622 Sqrt[a[t]])/(Pi (a[t])^2), a[0] == 0.5}, a, {t, 0, 500}]
Plot[a[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 500}]
a[t] /. sol /. t -> 432
```

[image]

what I want to do is the opposite, to input the 3 and get the 432 in the same graph, if possible to conserve the first result, in this case the 432 is a value that i know, but otherwise I wouldn't know. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sol` to define a function `func`. Then you can use `InverseFunction[func]`

```
func[t_] := a[t] /. sol[[1]]

Plot[func[t], {t, 0, 500}]
```

[image]

```
func[432]
```

> ```
> 3.002
> ```

```
InverseFunction[func][3.002]
```

> ```
> 431.9649
> ```

Comment: what does the extracted  [[1]] do?

Comment: @Sosa, it takes the first solution from `sol` (which is a _list of lists_) so that `func[432]` returns a number. Without it `func[432]` would return `{3.002}`, and `InverseFunction[func]` would not work as needed.